# TailwindCSS: Scrollable central panel being covered by footer component on mobile

Tags: css, tailwind-css

https://play.tailwindcss.com/notWWuhDpr?size=546x752

I have three main components:

1. header
2. main panel that's scrollable
3. footer

It was fairly simple to make this work in web with the code above (as shown in above link), but the main panel acts weirdly on mobile such as in [this video](https://imgur.com/a/kheJmcP), where bottom portion is covered by the bottom navbar with an odd scroll behavior. The first scroll is what I intend, where it scrolls through overflowed content. But the second scroll (when I scroll on the side edge) the entire panel component moves up and down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are referring to as "acts weirdly". But I do think it's better to have the entire screen make room for your elements instead of using a fixed variable for the footer as such [Tailwind preview](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0ljxvZyBl0?size=424x751):

```html
<div class="flex h-screen flex-col">
  <div class="flex-none">
    <div class="m-4 flex w-[calc(100vw-2rem)] space-x-2 rounded-lg bg-gray-300 p-4 shadow-md">Header</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow overflow-hidden">
    <div class="m-4 rounded-t-lg bg-white shadow-lg">
      <div class="mx-auto max-w-2xl p-6">
        <!-- mainpanel -->
        <div class="h-[calc(100vh-15rem)] overflow-y-scroll">
          <text class="text-5xl"> Lorem ipsum orem ipsumorem ipsumorem ipsupsumorem ipsumorem ipsupsumorem ipsumorem ipsumorem ipsumorem ipsumoremorem ipsumorem ipsumorem ipsumorem ipsumoremorem ipsumorem ipsumorem ipsumorem ipsumorem ipsumorem ipsumorem ipsumorem ipsum{" "} </text>
          <textarea>asdf</textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="m-4 mt-0 w-[calc(100vw-2rem)] rounded-b-lg border-t-2 border-gray-200 bg-gray-300 shadow-lg">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-center space-x-4 p-4">
        <button class="btn-solid h-10 w-32 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-gray-100">hello</button>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

For the other part with the scroll, I see that the font size is quite large in the mobile view and therefore go outside viewport, which adds a scroll direction X, which for most users is not intuitive.

I would therefore recommend you to have a smaller fort size for mobile view by changing the `text-5xl` to maybe a `text-3xl md:text-5xl`so that this large font scaling only kicks in when it has room for it.

I hope that this can help you onto the right path. Have a great day!